# Ich habe vorbereitet oder ich bin vorbereitet

Tags: grammaticality

When would one use the term `"Ich habe vorbereitet...."` and when `"Ich bin vorbereitet..."`?

`"Ich habe vorbereitet"` appears in lists as the perfect conjunction of *"vorbereiten"* but it is common to hear Germans say `"Ich bin vorbereitet..."` in everyday speech.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Both are used but mean different things. *Vorbereiten* means to prepare something.

## Ich habe ... vorbereitet

This is the 1st person singular *Perfekt* of *vorbereiten*. This means I (have) prepared something, e.g.

> Ich habe die Präsentation vorbereitet *I (have) prepared the presentation*

I put *have* in brackets, because Germans frequently use the *Perfekt* where English people would use the *simple past* (in spoken language).

## Ich bin vorbereitet

This uses the participle of *vorbereiten* as an adjective

> Ich bin vorbereitet *I am prepared*

Similiar to *Ich bin groß (I am tall)*

Comment: To supplement: *Nachdem ich _mich_ vier Wochen lang vorbereitet _habe_, _bin_ ich jetzt gut vorbereitet*.

Comment: This is common with transitive verbs in general: with *haben* it's the perfect tense, but with *sein* it's a participle adjective. The adjective can be used attributively as well, with proper declension of course: *Ich lese vorbereitete Notizen vor.*